# DeepEqual treats array initialized with back tick differently?

Tags: arrays, string, go, slice

My question is quite simple, I use back tick to initiate a string array, but I found that golang treats this array differently:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    x := []string{`hello world`, "me"}
    y := []string{"hello", "world", "me"}
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(x, y))
}
```

The output is:

```
[hello world me]
[hello world me]
false
```

This makes me confused: should I make sure all string arrays are initiated in the same way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), not [arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types), and your first slice has 2 elements, and the second has 3 elements, so how could they be equal?

Try printing them like this:

```
fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", len(x), x)
fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", len(y), y)
```

Output:

```
2 ["hello world" "me"]
3 ["hello" "world" "me"]
```

[`fmt.Prinln()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) will print all values of the passed slice, printing a space between elements. And first element of `x` is a string which equals to the first 2 elements of `y` joined with a space, that's why you see equal printed content for the slices.

When you use the same 3 strings to initialize your first slice with backticks, they will be equal:

```
x = []string{`hello`, `world`, "me"}
y = []string{"hello", "world", "me"}
fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", len(x), x)
fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", len(y), y)
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(x, y))
```

Output:

```
3 ["hello" "world" "me"]
3 ["hello" "world" "me"]
true
```

Try these on the <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/b46ySGQHfc)</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks @icza, very detailed explanation!